# trying to run in parallel for cucumber junit not working

Tags: maven, cucumber, junit4

I added the parallel and threadcount lines to surefire plugin configuration in pom file:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <parallel>all</parallel>
          <threadCount>2</threadCount>
          <argLine>-Xmx4g</argLine>
          <!--
          <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
          -->
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <databaseSchema>MY_TEST_SCHEMA_${surefire.forkNumber}</databaseSchema>
            <allure.results.directory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</allure.results.directory>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
          <includes>
            <include>**/Test*.java</include>
            <include>**/*Test.java</include>
            <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
            <include>**/*TestCase.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

When I run a few tests with maven I see `Running parallel.Test_RunCucumber` and I can see that multiple browsers are spawned. The problem is it only seems to execute tests in a single browser instance. The spawned browser instances are all "empty".

Here's one of the tests. The other is identical just goes to different sites.

```
Feature: Scenario Outlines feature file

  Scenario Outline: <site>
#    Given Step from '<scen_out_row_num>' in 'scenario-outlines' feature file
    Given the user navigates to home page '<site>'

    Examples:
      | site       |
      | https://google.com/ |
      | https://nationalpost.com/ |
      | https://ottawacitizen.com/ |
```

I've also tried using the failsafe plugin, but doesn't seem to make any difference.

I also tried following the example here:https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/?lang=java#junit-4. My output though indicates all running on the same thread
In the example the first test is:

```
  Scenario Outline: <scen_out_row_num>
    Given Step from '<scen_out_row_num>' in 'scenario-outlines' feature file

    Examples:
      | scen_out_row_num       |
      | Scenario Outline Row 1 |
      | Scenario Outline Row 2 |
```

The second is:

```
Feature: Scenarios feature file

  Scenario: Scenario Number One
    Given Step from 'Scenario 1' in 'scenarios' feature file

  Scenario: Scenario Number Two
    Given Step from 'Scenario 2' in 'scenarios' feature file
```

And the step def is:

```
    @Given("Step from {string} in {string} feature file")
    public void step(String scenario, String file) {
        System.out.format("@@@ Thread ID - %2d - %s from %s feature 
            file.\n", Thread.currentThread().getId(), 
            scenario,file);
    }
```

```
@@@ Thread ID -  1 - Scenario Outline Row 1 from scenario-outlines feature file.
@@@ Thread ID -  1 - Scenario Outline Row 2 from scenario-outlines feature file.
@@@ Thread ID -  1 - Scenario 1 from scenarios feature file.
@@@ Thread ID -  1 - Scenario 2 from scenarios feature file.
```

### CODE TO RUN

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <selenium.version>4.16.1</selenium.version>
    <cucumber.version>7.15.0</cucumber.version>
  </properties>
  <groupId>postmedia-automated-testing</groupId>
  <artifactId>postmedia-automated-testing</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>11</source>
          <target>11</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <parallel>all</parallel>
          <threadCount>4</threadCount>
          <includes>
            <include>**/Test*.java</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
      <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
      <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
      <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
      <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>5.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

src/test/resources/features/feature_1.feature

```
Feature: Navigate to https://google.com
  Scenario: Verify navigation to https://google.com
    Given the user navigates to home page "https://google.com"
```

src/test/resources/features/feature_2.feature

```
Feature: Navigate to  https://microsoft.com
  Scenario: Verify navigation to  https://microsoft.com
    Given the user navigates to home page "https://microsoft.com"
```

src/test/java/steps/StepDefs.java

```
package steps;

import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class StepDefs {
     private WebDriver driver;

    @Before()
    public void launchBrowser() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @After()
    public void quitDriver() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Given("the user navigates to home page {string}")
    public void navigateToHomePage(String url) throws InterruptedException {
        driver.navigate().to(url);
        System.out.println("@@@ navigated to site: " + url);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

src/test/java/steps/Test_RunCucumber.java

```
package steps;

import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class StepDefs {
     private WebDriver driver;

    @Before()
    public void launchBrowser() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    @After()
    public void quitDriver() {
        driver.quit();
    }

    @Given("the user navigates to home page {string}")
    public void navigateToHomePage(String url) throws InterruptedException {
        driver.navigate().to(url);
        System.out.println("@@@ navigated to site: " + url);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `cucumber-junit` you can only execute features in parallel. This due to technical limitations in JUnit 4.

If you upgrade to JUnit 5, you can use the `cucumber-junit-platform-engine` which can execute scenarios and examples in parallel.

See the example project and docs

- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton
- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine#parallel-execution

Comment: Both my test and the test from cucumber docs are running 2 feature files. But not seeing parallel execution. When I run with <forkCount>2</forkCount> I see 2 jvms and 2 browsers, both performing tasks. But when I run parallel I see multiple browser instances, but only 1 browser instance is actually performing the tasks

Comment: These are the only references to junit on classpath:  /.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-junit4/3.2.3/surefire-junit4-3.2.3.jar
 /.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/common-junit4/3.2.3/common-junit4-3.2.3.jar
 /.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/surefire/common-junit3/3.2.3/common-junit3-3.2.3.jar
 /.m2/repository/io/cucumber/cucumber-junit/7.15.0/cucumber-junit-7.15.0.jar
 /.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.13.2/junit-4.13.2.jar
 /.m2/repository/org/junit/jupiter/junit-jupiter-api/5.10.1/junit-jupiter-api-5.10.1.jar:

Comment: Mmh. The browser thing could be because the web driver is assigned to a static variable. For everything else you're in MCVE territory.

Comment: I've added all the code to run the tests in parallel. I think I've got everything. If I missed something let me know. Thanks

Comment: Your `includes` don't match your test name. So Maven wouldn't run anything. It would be prudent to make a minimal reproducer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example you could use

Comment: Doesn't `            <include>**/Test*.java</include>` match the runner class name of `Test_RunCucumber.java`? Works fine on my local when I run `mvn clean test`

Comment: I have `StepDefs.java` and `Test_RunCucumber.java` under `src/test/java/parallel` And I have the 2 feature files under `src/test/resources/parallel`

Comment: Not without an MCVE I'm afraid. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You can use the skeleton as a starting point though https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton/

Comment: OK I get it now. Will attempt to set up. Thanks

Comment: I have changed the code under sub-heading "code to run" which hopefully qualifies as an MCVE. In doing so, I discovered that when I commented out the `junit-jupiter-api` dependency (last one in pom), running in parallel worked. If you're intention was for me to figure it out on my own M.P. Korstanje - kudos. Now the question is why does that dependency mess up running in parallel.

Comment: Honestly, I'm more puzzled than you are right now. Surefire has a mechanism to switch between JUnit 4/5 but that shouldn't come into effect with just the JUnit Jupiter API, and if it did, your tests wouldn't run at all. And everything else looks okay.

Comment: That's fine. I tried running a portion of our existing tests without the jupiter dependency (don't think it's even used) and just 2 threads and it's a disaster. Don't think we'll be pursuing it. But really appreciate the help. Would it be a good idea to write as the answer that the jupiter api dependency was what was causing the problem, so other's can easily view?

Comment: It might be useful to someone. Shame it didn't work out. Though parallel execution also isn't simple, so quite understandable.